# How to add a scrollbar to h:selectOneMenu?

Tags: jsf-2

I have created a JSF Facelets document. In that document, I am working with dropdown list using `<h:selectOneMenu>` tag. How can I add a scrollbar to this dropdown menu and after click of the dropdownlist the values should displayed in downward direction?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the size attribute.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.value}" size="1">
  <f:selectitems value="#{myBean.selectOptions}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: size attribute is available in html code only. size="1" not working

Comment: The dropdownbox has contains the maximum values (>13) so It will shows the values in upward direction. My solution is it must be shows downward direction after selecting the dropdown.

Comment: kindly can you tell me what change I will do?

Comment: Oh. You can only limit/increase the initial size of options that are available and I'm not sure if you can influence the direction. The h:selectOneMenu renders a basic html "select". You should ask your questions for a basic select and see if you can solve your problem with css.